# NullPointerException when adding a new Fragment to a ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentstatepageradapter

I'm willing to add a dynamic number of fragments to a ViewPager in my android app, so that I'm using the following way:

The **FragmentActivity**:

```
public class Lighting extends FragmentActivity {

     private LightPageAdapter TabAdapter;
     private VerticalViewPager Tab;
     private List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();

     // to add a new Fragment
     public void fragmenting() {
        Bundle page = new Bundle();
        page.putString("somedata", "somedata");
        Fragment frag = Fragment.instantiate(this,MyFragment.class.getName(),page); // this is where I got the Exception
        fragments.add(frag);
     }

     //to init the Page adapter
     public void init_page_adapter(){
        this.TabAdapter  = new LightPageAdapter(super.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
        Tab = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.lighting_pager);
        Tab.setAdapter(this.TabAdapter);
     }

}
```

The **PageAdapter**:

```
public class LightPageAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private List<Fragment> myFragments;

    public LightPageAdapter (FragmentManager fragmentManager, List<Fragment> fragments) {
        super(fragmentManager);

        myFragments = fragments;

    }

    public Fragment getItem(int i) {

        return myFragments.get(i);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return myFragments.size();

    }

}
```

The **Fragment**:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

  @Override
      public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
              Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          View lighting_fragment = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lighting_fragment, container, false);
          return lighting_fragment;
      }

}
```

The **ErrorLog**:

```
05-07 08:17:45.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1533): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-07 08:17:45.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1533): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-07 08:17:45.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getClassLoader(ContextWrapper.java:122)
05-07 08:17:45.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:399)
05-07 08:17:45.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at com.automation.isolace.Lighting.fragmenting(Lighting.java:1301)
05-07 08:17:45.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at com.automation.fragments.Light_Center.onViewCreated(Light_Center.java:46)
05-07 08:17:45.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:941)
05-07 08:17:45.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
05-07 08:17:45.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
05-07 08:17:45.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
05-07 08:17:45.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:472)
05-07 08:17:45.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:163)
05-07 08:17:45.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1068)
05-07 08:17:45.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
05-07 08:17:45.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1436)
05-07 08:17:45.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
05-07 08:17:45.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:833)
05-07 08:17:45.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
05-07 08:17:45.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
05-07 08:17:45.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:617)
05-07 08:17:45.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:399)
05-07 08:17:45.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
05-07 08:17:45.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
05-07 08:17:45.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
05-07 08:17:45.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
05-07 08:17:45.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
05-07 08:17:45.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1390)
05-07 08:17:45.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
05-07 08:17:45.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
05-07 08:17:45.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
05-07 08:17:45.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
05-07 08:17:45.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
05-07 08:17:45.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2148)
05-07 08:17:45.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
05-07 08:17:45.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1848)
05-07 08:17:45.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1100)
05-07 08:17:45.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1273)
05-07 08:17:45.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:998)
05-07 08:17:45.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4212)
05-07 08:17:45.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
05-07 08:17:45.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
05-07 08:17:45.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
05-07 08:17:45.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
05-07 08:17:45.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
05-07 08:17:45.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-07 08:17:45.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-07 08:17:45.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
05-07 08:17:45.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-07 08:17:45.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-07 08:17:45.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
05-07 08:17:45.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
05-07 08:17:45.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please paste the error log as well.

Comment: Do you still get error calling constructor? `new MyFragment()`? That's all instantiate does really, plus it calls set args with that bundle, but personally I'd do that over the instantiate which as it takes a string name is clearly intended for loading fragments without source code dependency.

Comment: @Kedarnath I forgot to post it, now the question updated with it

Comment: @weston No, I tried to separate it , so that I'm getting all of it's parameters each one alone before calling that line and everything goes well with each parameter alone but when calling instantiate it crashes

Comment: I'm unclear, does it crash when you call `new MyFragment()` instead of `Fragment.instantiate`?

Comment: @weston No, it only crashes when calling `Fragment.instantiate`

Comment: @weston your point is to try `fragments.add(new MyFragment());` ?

Comment: Yeah, `Fragment frag = new MyFragment(); frag.setArguments(page);` will do the same as the `Fragment.instantiate` line.

Comment: @weston well, that solved it, you can add it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Fragment frag = new MyFragment();
frag.setArguments(page);
```

Will do the same as the `Fragment.instantiate` line.

`Instantiate` should only be used when you don't have a source code dependency to the fragment. i.e. you only have a `String` name of the class, not access to the class itself.

The cause is unclear, but it could be that `MyFragment` is a v11 fragment, and you try to create it with a v4 `Fragment.instantiate`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Lighting` activity is not properly instantiated. You probably created it with `new` somewhere. Never instantiate activities with `new` - use an `Intent` to instantiate if you really need to.

Specifically, the exception is because the base context of the activity is not set up. The framework would do it for you before calling activity `onCreate()` when instantiating with an `Intent`.

Comment: that gave me another way to solve my problem, I'm already do use `Intent` not `new` but when trying to add these `Fragments` I'm in a `Fragmweent` inside the `Activity`, So, using the `Context` of the `Fragment` not the `Activity` solved the problem.